# Member function declared with 'override' does not override a base class member C++

Tags: c++

I just don't understand why the compiler wont override the function.
I tried adding the cos function which did not give any errors, and I don't see the difference between the two cases.

using VS I get the error:

> "Member function declared with 'override' does not override a base class member"
> when hovering mouse over the function name. Also a bunch of errors when compiling.

I also wonder if i want to override it in this same headerfile and then implement them in a cpp file, should I keep the override word, or is it only used during the declaration of the overriden function?

```
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include<glm/gtc/quaternion.hpp>
...

struct Collider 
{
    virtual CollisionPoints TestCollision(
        const Transform* transform,
        const Collider* collider,
        const Transform* colliderTransform) const = 0;

    virtual CollisionPoints TestCollision(
        const Transform* transform,
        const SphereCollider* sphere,
        const Transform* sphereTransform) const = 0;

    virtual CollisionPoints TestCollision(
        const Transform* transform,
        const PlaneCollider* plane,
        const Transform* planeTransform) const = 0;

    virtual float cos(float theta) const = 0;


struct SphereCollider : Collider 
{
    glm::vec2 center;
    float radius;

    CollisionPoints TestCollision(
        const Transform* transform,
        const Collider* collider,
        const Transform* colliderTransform) const override;

    CollisionPoints TestCollision(   //highlighted error on this function name
        const Transform* transform,
        const SphereCollider* sphere,
        const Transform* sphereTransform) const override;

    CollisionPoints TestCollision(  //highlighted error on this function name
        const Transform* transform,
        const PlaneCollider* plane,
        const Transform* planeTransform) const override;

    float cos(float theta) const override
    {
        return glm::cos(theta);
    }

};
```

Comment: please include the error message in the question

Comment: cannot reproduce. After adding the missing `};` and some forward declarations, the code you posted compiles: https://godbolt.org/z/YEjWTed3G

Comment: Please try to include a [mcve] and the complete error message in the question.

Comment: do you have a forward declaration of `ShereCollider` in your real code? The errors about the overrides might be just due to other previous errors. Tip: Look at the compiler error, what your IDE says can be misleading to find the actual cause

Comment: Forward declaration without the implementation curlybraces {} : "struct CollisionPoints;
struct Transform;
struct SphereCollider;
struct PlaneCollider;" Worked great thanks. I'lI will read up on this some more. Yeah, the IDE gave me 50 errors so maybe there was some good information in there that i missed.

Comment: @JohnLarsson A general tip is to initially ignore everything except the first error, as following errors can often be "knock-on" effects of the first error.